# iOS UICollectionView itemSize is different between collectionViews which based on the same UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

I used a 3rd lib called PagingMenuController to display several collectionViews in the mainview, and set the itemSize width equal to collectionView's width and height for collectionView's width / 1.5, but in different collectionViews, the itemSize is different and even in the same collectionView the size is also not the same.

All these collectionView's code and setting in storyboard are the same.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell
    var imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as? UIImageView
    if imageView == nil {
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView!.bounds.width, self.collectionView!.bounds.width / 1.5))
        imageView!.tag = 100
        imageView!.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView!)
    }
    imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView!.bounds.width, self.collectionView!.bounds.width / 1.5)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

I tried to set the width to be UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, now all the collectionView behave the same, but there are some insets in the left where it should be 0.

Can someone figure out what cause this and how to solve it? Thanks.

[image: when the width set to be self.collectionView!.bounds.width, one of the weird collectionView][image: when the width set to be self.collectionView!.bounds.width, one of the normal collectionView]][image: when the width set to be UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, there are some margins in left, but I set it to be 0]

Comment: Are you using auto layout? What happens when you change self.collectionView!.bounds to collectionView.bounds in the functions you posted?

Comment: @beyowulf I'm using Auto Layout. I changed the self.collectionView!.bounds to collectionView.bounds, but still the same result